# mongoose: applying $addToSet of the object value inside the array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
game_data: [{
   id: 'HUH',
   name: 'GTA'
   story: 'ahhhh'
}]
```

I have a field like above. I want to check incoming data to avoid duplicate on the value `id`.

```
incomingg_dataA: {
       id: 'HUH',
       name: 'Dota2'
       story: 'hmmm'
    }
```

Like this case, if the `incomingg_dataA` contains the same id `HUH`. I want to use that value to `$addToSet`. If the id is different

```
incomingg_dataB: {
       id: 'HUUUH',
       name: 'Dota2'
       story: 'hmmm'
    }
```

then, it would be

```
game_data: [{
   id: 'HUH',
   name: 'GTA'
   story: 'ahhhh'
}, 
{
   id: 'HUUUH',
   name: 'Dota2'
   story: 'hmmm'
}];
```

I could do the entire document as `$addToSet` but then, I am kinda afraid that someone will just change the `story` part and it will still be registered.

Is there any way that I can do this with `$addToSet` or do I just have to do the .find() and callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `$ne` condition in your find query with the `id` value you want to avoid duplicate.

```js
db.col.update({
  // All the find conditions you want
  // Plus the below condition
  "game_data.id": {"$ne": incomingg_dataB['id']},  // Updated only when the `id` is not already present in the array
}, {
  "$push": {
    "game_data": incomingg_dataB,
  }
})
```